# Need help converting a package to catkin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm hoping some kind hearted catkin expert can help me convert my rosbuild package to catkin.  The package is [skeleton_markers](https://github.com/pirobot/skeleton_markers/tree/hydro-devel) and unfortunately the [catkinize](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Migration_Help_-_.22Catkinize.22_Scripts) script seems to be currently [broken](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkinize/issues/38) for simple packages (though it works OK for stacks).

While I can piece together some of the parts, I can't get the whole thing to work, especially the dependencies on NITE and OpenNI for my cpp executable.  Here are the current manifest.xml and CMakeLists.txt files:

manifest.xml:

```
<package>
  <description brief="skeleton_markers">
    Skeleton Markers: Publish a list of joint markers for viewing in RViz
  </description>
  <author>Patrick Goebel</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/skeleton_markers</url>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="visualization_msgs"/>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="geometry_msgs"/>
  <depend package="openni_camera"/>
  <depend package="openni_tracker"/>

  <export>
    <cpp cflags="-I/usr/include/openni -I/usr/include/nite -I/usr/include/ni"/>
  </export>
 
</package>
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
rosbuild_genmsg()

#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
include_directories(/usr/include/openni /usr/include/nite /usr/include/ni)
rosbuild_add_executable(skeleton_tracker src/skeleton_tracker.cpp src/KinectController.cpp src/KinectDisplay.cpp)
target_link_libraries(skeleton_tracker glut OpenNI orocos-kdl tf)
```

Can anyone convert these to the corresponding package.xml and CMakeLists.txt files for catkin?

**UPDATE**:  Here are the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt files I came up with after looking at these files for the openni_tracker package.  Below the two files I list the error messages I get when compiling.

package.xml

```
<package>
  <name>skeleton_markers</name>
  <version>0.4.0</version>
  <description>
   Skeleton Markers: Publish a list of joint markers 
   for viewing in RViz.
  </description>

  <maintainer email="patrick@pirobot.org">Patrick Goebel</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url type="website">http://ros.org/wiki/skeleton_markers</url>
  <url type="https://github.com/pirobot/skeleton_markers/issues"></url>
  <author email="patrick@pirobot.org">Patrick Goebel</author>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>libopenni-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libopenni-nite-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>orocos_kdl</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>openni_camera</build_depend>
  <build_depend>openni_tracker</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>

  <run_depend>libopenni-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libopenni-nite-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>orocos_kdl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>openni_camera</run_depend>
  <run_depend>openni_tracker</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>

<!--
  <export>
    <cpp cflags="-I/usr/include/openni -I/usr/include/nite -I/usr/include/ni"/>
  </export>
-->
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(skeleton_markers)

find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS geometry_msgs message_generation)

# Find OpenNI
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(OpenNI REQUIRED libopenni)

# Find Nite
find_path(Nite_INCLUDEDIR
          NAMES XnVNite.h
          HINTS /usr/include/nite /usr/local/include/nite)
find_library(Nite_LIBRARY
             NAMES XnVNite_1_3_1
             HINTS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
             PATH_SUFFIXES lib) 

link_directories(
  ${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  ${OpenNI_LIBRARIES}
  ${Nite_LIBRARY}
)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDEDIR}
                    ${OpenNI_INCLUDEDIR}
                    ${Nite_INCLUDEDIR}
                    ${orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_message_files (
  FILES
  Skeleton.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
    DEPENDS rospy roscpp visualization_msgs std_msgs geometry_msgs
    openni_camera openni_tracker tf message_runtime
    CATKIN-DEPENDS # TODO
    INCLUDE_DIRS # TODO include
    LIBRARIES # TODO
)

add_executable(skeleton_tracker
  src/skeleton_tracker.cpp
  src/KinectController.cpp
  src/KinectDisplay.cpp)

target_link_libraries(skeleton_tracker
  glut
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenNI_LIBRARIES}
  ${Nite_LIBRARY}
  ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})
```

And when I run catkin_make, I get the errors below:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/f75185aecb53aeb63d51e48c7a1bb66e

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113526/need-help-converting-a-package-to-catkin/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3706 on 2013-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing the following line in your CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS geometry_msgs message_generation)
```

to

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp tf geometry_msgs message_generation)
```

---

Originally posted by [mardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10151/mardo/) with karma: 126 on 2013-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
Thanks Sam!  That did the trick (almost).  I also had to add tf to the list of components.  If you edit your answer and add tf, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `include_directories()` also include wrong variables. It should be

```
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
```

It might work for you since `orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS` might point to the same path.

Generally if you are unsure about some variables names it help to just output them in order to verify that you named them correctly and that they contain the right information:

```
message("DEBUG variable catkin_INCLUDEDIR: ${catkin_INCLUDEDIR}")
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-29**:
Thanks for the tip!